# Add <HTML> to order-status column in WooCommerce "My account" orders table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I want to style the content of some order columns in the list of orders (My Account area).
The problem is, that every content starts without any elements which I could use for styling.

For example: I want to give the order status a background color like a badge.
At the moment the status is the only content in the column. Like this:

```
<td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-status" data-title="Status">
    Completed
</td>
```

I want to change it to this:

```
<td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-status" data-title="Status">
    <span class="badge badge-success">Completed</span>
</td>
```

The `class` is an option. I could also style the simple `<span>` based on he class of the `<td>`.

Is there any way to change the output of the columns without touching the template file?
It's a very crucial template and I don't want to change it for such a simple addition.

In the template I saw this action before the content of each column:

```
<?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
```

Is there a way to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed the correct way, use the column id *'order-status'* in this case

> woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_**{$column_id}**

```php
function my_callback( $order ) {
    echo '<span class="badge badge-success">' . esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ) . '</span>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-status', 'my_callback', 10, 1 );
```